# Is it possible to use Entity client connection string to sql connection of store procedure in mvc?

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, web-config

Hi i want to know that how to use entity client connection string to sql connection of store procedure. Now i am connecting one db as Edmx file using Ado.net.
so that i can get some default connection string  in that web.config file.Now i am creating one store procedure in db and connect that store procedure as edmx file.

Then i used that in one controller. Now i have to declare sql connection to execute store procedure like

```
SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("DataSource")
```

In this same database name only i am using. So instead of writing connection code for every time i can call my web.config connetion string name.So that while deploying 
my project in online that time i will change dbname in web.config file. so that i can use every where once i call this connection string ever where.
Now what i want is how to use Entity client connection string to sql connection . Is it possible in mvc.

**My web.config file connceton string**

```
<Connectionstring>
<add name="COSECEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.dbCOSEC.csdl|res://*/Models.dbCOSEC.ssdl|res://*/Models.dbCOSEC.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=ADMIN-PC;initial catalog=COSEC;user id=sa;password=sql;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

**My Controller (Exception)**

```
 public class UserMasterController : Controller
  {
    private COSECEntities db = new COSECEntities();

    SqlConnection conn =new SqlConnection("Data Source=ADMIN-PC;Initial Catalog=COSEC;User ID=sa;Password=sql;");
}
```

Now if i change the db name in web.config file means also i have to change where ever the i wrote sql connection place too.But if i call that web config file connection 
string name means it is enough to change in one place right.

I tried to call that web.config file connection in my controller but i got error that is can't use entity client connection strin to sql connection.Code is below.

**Exception Controller**

```
    public class UserMasterController : Controller
    {
      private COSECEntities db = new COSECEntities();
      string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["COSECEntities"].ConnectionString;
      SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
      con.Open();
    }
```

if i change the provider name from entity clent to sql client in web.config file means another operations stopped working.

i tried my level best to explain my issue. Any one understand my issue and help me to resolve this problem

Thanks..

Comment: You can use connection string used by entity framework itself, it is stored in "db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString" (where db is instance of COSECEntities).

Comment: Please can you explain your answer detaily with some example. so that i can understand easily

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can reuse connection used by Entity Framework itself, like this:

```
using (var db = new COSECEntities()) {
    SqlConnection con = (SqlConnection) db.Database.Connection;
}
```

If for whatever reason you need to create new connection, you can reuse connection string:

```
using (var db = new COSECEntities()) {
    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(db.Database.Connection.ConnectionString)) {

    }
}
```

If you don't have access to entity framework context or don't want to create it, you can get provider connection string from entity framework connection string like this:

```
var cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["COSECEntities"].ConnectionString;
var providerCs = new EntityConnectionStringBuilder(cs).ProviderConnectionString;
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(providerCs);
```

Comment: ok suppose i have two connection string in web.config file means how i use this method

Comment: OK I have a try and let you know evk

Comment: I am getting A field initializer cannot reference the non static
field method or Property near to cs (EntityConnectionStringBuilder(cs)) and Provider cs and also i m geeting error near to var that error is a type or namespace var could not be found..